# Socket wrench turns loose on top of spark plug

Tags: maintenance, sparkplugs, prius

I'm trying to replace the spark plugs of my 2006 Prius, but the deep well 5/8 socket attached to a 2 in extender just turns loose, as if it does not fit in the top of the spark plug. I tried also 3/4 and 13/16 but those don't even fit in the spark plug well. I tried in another spark plug to the same result. What could I do to remove the spark plug?

Comment: Do you have a new, replacement plug?  Does the socket fit on it?

Comment: It sounds like you rounded off the spark plug head. Can you confirm this? A picture would help too

Comment: Also, have you tried using a dedicated spark plug socket with rubber boot instead of just a deep-well?

Comment: The correct size is a 5/8 socket. Are you sure the little rubber grommet inside of it (to hold the plug for removal) is not in the way? It can stop you from being able to get a good grip on the plug body.

Comment: I can confirm that @racefever is correct ... it's a 5/8" deepwell (or spark plug) socket to remove the plug. Also, even on a deep well, I wouldn't think 2" worth of extension is going to be enough to get the job done ...

Comment: @Paulster2 Is right, you need a 6 inch extension minimum.  OP: check the link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NojMqehlJLY

Comment: @racefever - Would you please join us in the chatroom? [The Pitstop](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/340/the-pitstop).

Comment: @racefever I'm doing exactly as in the video and the extension seems to be ok for what I'm doing since the socket makes it to the bottom and I have space to turn the wrench. The part in the top of the spark plug comes out as a whole without leaving any rubber part inside, as in the video. The only thing that seems different is that I'm using a regular deep well 5/8 socket and in the video they are using a spark plug socket. I will go to AutoZone to check if they have one of these and try again.

Comment: @Zaid I can't see anything inside the socket well since it is under the body, so I cannot look directly over it. Maybe a mirror will do it. And I stilt didn't buy the new spark plugs since I just want to check the condition of the current ones (I bought the car recently).

Comment: @gabrieldiego You do need the 5/8 spark plug socket. The inside of the socket allows the spark plug body to fit. Otherwise the socket innards just hit the spark plug body. Its a typical mistake! (:

Comment: @Zaid I bought the right wrench this afternoon and replaced the spark plugs. Everything worked fine and car is running smoother now. You can post an answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A dedicated spark plug socket is the way to go here.

Regular deep well sockets don't work because the spark plug electrode will interfere with the square drive end. This is also why an extension will not help; there is nowhere for the electrode to be accommodated.